# How to find a space curve given curvature and torsion?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I am trying to compute curves, given curvature and torsion. For the plane, I got the formula from a book in differential geometry and just constructed numerical approximations for it. As an instance, see the curve for the curvature $\kappa(s)=s^2 \sin(s)$:

> [image]

Now I am trying to compute for space curves, until now I did the following:

> [image]

If I am thinking correctly, I computed a numerical interpolation for ${T}(s),{N}(s)$ and ${B}(s)$. What do I do now? How do I get the parametrization for the curve? Is it by integrating ${T}(s)$? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Right. Having solved the system fir $T,N,B$, you then integrate $T$ to get the parametric curve (initial conditions on all four).

Comment: @TedShifrin [It worked!](https://i.imgur.com/q6UPYum.png) Thank you!